Cannot find Mesa though the installation succeeded
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
I'm trying to install pylon Viewer and according to instructions I need to install the latest Mesa OpenGL driver. I followed the instructions from here:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

But, when I later run glxinfo | grep Mesa it returns nothing. Does it mean it failed installing Mesa though there are no errors?
Actually when I ran the first command sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa I got this message, but I continued by pressing Enter.

UPDATE
I tried sudo apt install mesa, but I get E: Unable to locate package mesa. Also, when I do glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version" it returns OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 535.171.04. Shouldn't it return Mesa and not Nvidia?

Try the install command in the instruction link you provided:sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0

@ubfan1, yes I did this, and then they say If the pylon Viewer still can't be started, install the latest Mesa OpenGL driver. Since the pylon Viewer can't be started I was trying to install Mesa driver.

You haven't installed mesa yet. Do:
sudo apt install meda

What you have done is:

Added the PPA
Updated all the package indexes.
Performed updates required by already installed packages.

And then you stopped.

Are you sure? There is no such step in the link I provided in the post. But, regardless, sudo apt install mesa returns E: Unable to locate package mesa. I also updated my post showing that I get Nvidia instead of Mesa when I run glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

ok, I added UPDATE section trying what you suggested. Can you suggest what can I try next?
